# Bool Tool diffrence not working

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier

Im trying to bool difference on this cube to make hole in shape of cylinder but the only thing i get in cut in shape of it. It works the other way around, it means when im trying to cuta cylinder with cube.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you tried the Fast option of the Boolean modifier? Maybe share your file. Also it's generally better to use less vertices when you model

Comment: Also worth checking that the Face Normal Orientation is correct on both objects.